# BIRT - org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.OdaDataException: Cannot get the result set metadata

Tags: mysql, eclipse, exception, jdbc, birt

In BIRT, When i try to fetch the records from my localhost, its working fine. But when i try to work with remote connection i am getting error as specified below:

**Error :**

```
org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.OdaDataException: Cannot get the result set metadata.
        org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCException: SQL statement does not return a ResultSet object.
    SQL error #1:Table 'test.TBLUSERS' doesn't exist ... 63 more

Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'testbms.TBLUSERS' doesn't exist

    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:936)

    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2985)
```

**Note:**

> **Tablenames are automatically changing to capital letters**, is that because of it.
>   Because client server is linux and is it acting with case sensitive.
>   But it displays column names but not the records. As soon as i click
>   on finish, i get the error as specified in the below images.

**Reference Image:**

[image]

As you can see in the above image, it has populated the table columns in the second row

Is their any special configurations need to be done for remote connection or am i doing anything wrong?

Comment: `But it displays column names but not the records` - check the privilges on your connection user.

Comment: I checked with privileges, its all perfect. It's just causing due to the conversion of small to capital letters. Its because of case sensitive. How to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

As you stated, it is probably a case of case-sensitivity:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html

> Although database and table names are not case sensitive on some
>   platforms, you should not refer to a given database or table using
>   different cases within the same statement. The following statement
>   would not work because it refers to a table both as my_table and as
>   MY_TABLE:  `mysql> SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE MY_TABLE.col=1;`

If your development box isn't case sensitive then when you change the case of your tablename to match that on production you'll still be able to test. There might also be a way in MySQL using system tables. (See the following query for an example of querying to see if a table exists.):

```
SELECT count(*) 
FROM information_schema.tables 
WHERE table_schema = <schema-or-db-name> 
AND table_name = <table-or-view-name>
```

but more realistically, your target database should be passed to your report through a variable that you can check in the scripting of the dataset. Set the "this.query" value to equal the appropriate query based on that variable's value.

E.G.:

```
if ( params["source_db"].value == "Server=myProductionAddress;Database=myProductionDB;Uid=myUsername;Pwd=myPassword;" )
{
  this.query = "SELECT .... prodTableName";
}
else
{
  this.query = "SELECT .... devTableName";
}
```